# ClassCastException android.widget.Button to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have no idea what I am doing wrong but i keep getting the following error with my SignInButton for Google+

```
09-02 19:26:56.245  12537-12537/com.ferdiseegers.klantenbestand E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ferdiseegers.klantenbestand/com.ferdiseegers.klantenbestand.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        at com.ferdiseegers.klantenbestand.Activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
        ... 11 more
```

**I used the button in my layout XML from the example project**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
     android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"/>
```

**And this is how I use it in my activity**

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
            PlusClient.ConnectionCallbacks, PlusClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener {

        private static final int DIALOG_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1;

        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 2;

        private TextView mSignInStatus;
        private PlusClient mPlusClient;
        private SignInButton mSignInButton;
        private View mSignOutButton;
        private View mRevokeAccessButton;
        private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                    .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                    .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE)
                    .build();

            mSignInStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_status);
            mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mSignOutButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
            mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mRevokeAccessButton = findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
            mRevokeAccessButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    //some other methods not worth pasting here

}
```

Its might be something simple but i have been struggling with it for 2 hours now. Hope anyone can give me a hand!

Comment: If you replaced Button with SignInButton in the layout file, try refreshing and clearing the project.  Also check if you have another Button somewhere in layout file with @+id/sign_in_button

Comment: Had a old button in the layout with the same id. Removed it and it works! Thanks for helping it!

Comment: @Y2i could you answer the question down so i can accept it?

Comment: Copied my comment to an answer.  Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replaced Button with SignInButton in the layout file, try refreshing and clearing the project. Also check if you have another Button somewhere in layout file with @+id/sign_in_button

Comment: There was indeed another button in the layout file with the same name! Problem solved thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast your `sign_in_button` under your layout `activity_login` into Class which is not equivalent to the class or super class of it which you describe in that `activity_login`.

As per assumption your `sign_in_button` is `Button` under your layout `activity_login`. So tried to cast with the same class or it's superclass.

Here's the code of line which is root cause of your `ClassCastException`.

```
mSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
```

You may also try to cast as Superclass of the `Button` which is `View`

```
mSignInButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
```

1. Note:   `Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.`

For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of private SignInButton signInButton try giving private View signInButton.I guess for your customclass SignInButton you might have extended View instead of Button.

Comment: Tryed that but didnt work. I had a old button with the same id in my layout file. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SignInButton google class then add
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleSignIn);

Make sure you will cast button

I did this today and it solved my problem.